# How to give proper paths of folders in D drive in python

Tags: python, path

This is my code. Basically i want to load all images in a folder inside my D drive in a loop.

```
 from PIL import Image
 def loadimages(path):
    list=listdir(path)
    loadedimages=[]
    for image in list:
        img=Image.open(path+image)
        loadedimages.append(img)
    return loadedimages

path= r"D:\ACADEMICS\8SEM\PatternClassification\CBT-1\TrainCharacters"
imgs=loadimages(path)
```

I am getting error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    imgs=loadimages(path)
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 5, in loadimages
    img=Image.open(path+image)
  File "C:\Users\anjana ouseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\ACADEMICS\\8SEM\\PatternClassification\\CBT-1\\TrainCharacters1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images are inside the TrainCharacters folder, you are missing a "\"

currently its looking for

```
'D:\\ACADEMICS\\8SEM\\PatternClassification\\CBT-1\\TrainCharacters1'
```

It's likely you need

```
'D:\\ACADEMICS\\8SEM\\PatternClassification\\CBT-1\\TrainCharacters\\1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is the line `img=Image.open(path+image)`.
I would recommend using the built-in Python path manipulation method `os.path.join`:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
def loadimages(path):
    list=listdir(path)
    loadedimages=[]
    for image in list:
        img=Image.open(os.path.join(path, image))
        loadedimages.append(img)
    return loadedimages

path= r"D:\ACADEMICS\8SEM\PatternClassification\CBT-1\TrainCharacters"
imgs=loadimages(path)
```